# Typescript observable never updated when i have only one instance

Tags: typescript, http, angular2-services

I work since many days on this problems but i never find why my observable doesn't work: It is not updated when modifications appear .. 
I try with other http request but i have this same problem.

How can I update my data in my angular component when there are new modifications ?

SERVICE :

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
[...]
getAllCodeBuildrun(projectCodebuildName : string): Observable<Response>{
  return  this._http
    .get(environment.baseURL + "/codebuildProject/"+projectCodebuildName+"/buildRun")
    // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    //...errors if any
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-application',
  templateUrl: './application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application.component.css']
})
[...]
ngOnInit() {   
  this.applicationsService.getAllCodeBuildrun("test").subscribe(
    buildsRun => {
              console.log('codeBuild :', buildsRun); // appear just one time in console 
              this.builds= buildsRun["builds"];
              }, 
    error => console.error('error', error)
  );
}
```

APP-MODULE.TS

```
providers: [
   ProjectsService
],
```

Comment: probably you are not doing  'next' to your observable whenever some value changes

Comment: The HTTP service does the job once. If you search for auto-update look in the direction of websocket or fetch the data using some sort of setInterval / observable.interval

Comment: observable is given by http request. 'next' is give also do by http

Comment: I think interval is not the good solution, i just want be alert/notificate when there is a new state

Comment: new ideas ? ????